# how to arrange and present service in wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have group of academies and manages received data in central office by a wcf service ,received data is as followed:

Teacher info :new teacher ,update teacher and delete teacher ,...

student info :new student ,update student and delete student ,...

...

how should i config my service address in `App.config` file that client can use my services by single `add service reference`?

this is my service contract:

```
public interface ITeacher
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Add(Teacher teacher);
        [OperationContract]
        void Update(Teacher teacher);

        [OperationContract]
        void Delete(Teacher teacher);
    } 

public interface IStudent
        {
            [OperationContract]
            void Add(Student student);
            [OperationContract]
            void Update(Student student)
            [OperationContract]
            void Delete(Student Student);
        }
```

Comment: I think for that you have to implement your both service contract under single service implementation.

Comment: should i merge services?

Comment: Yes. If you want single endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made two services contracts so you would have to have two endpoints in your app.config

I think you would be better off if you wrote your services contract like this:

```
public interface ISchool
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddTeacher(Teacher teacher);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateTeacher(Teacher teacher);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteTeacher(Teacher teacher);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddStudent(Student student);

    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateStudent(Student student)

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteDtudent(Student Student);
}
```

Then you would only need one end point for all of your commands.